# Cannot resolve nested path with snowpack

Tags: reactjs, snowpack

In my react project a hard refresh of a nested path does not work. Then [snowpack config](https://www.snowpack.dev/#configuration) tries to load from the folder "*dist*" and cannot serve the page.

config like in snowpack docu:

```
{
  mount: {
    public: '/',
    src: '/_dist_',
  },
   ...
 }
```

error

http://localhost:3000/myfolder/id

```
GET http://localhost:3000/myfolder/_dist_/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```